# Помощь в оптимизации кода c#

Tags: c#

Сам код принимает в первой строке два значения: количество мишеней и количество выстрелов, далее соответственное количество строк расположений мишеней на координатной плоскости, после соответственное количество координат попаданий, строка вывода выглядит следующим образом: для каждой пули по порядку, если пуля попала в мишень, то выводится номер мишени(в соответствии с порядком ввода их координат, дважды попасть в одну нельзя), если же не попала, то выводится -1

```
using System;

namespace game2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] a = Console.ReadLine().Split(' '); //принял значения первой строки
            int n = Int32.Parse(a[0]);
            int m = Int32.Parse(a[1]); //преобразование элементов массива в int
            int temp;
            int[] mas = new int[m];//объявление конечного массива
            int[,] bottleplace = new int[n, 4];//массив расположения бутылок
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                string[] c = Console.ReadLine().Split(' '); //прием координат бутылок по две точки(X Y нижней левой точки, X Y верхней правой)
                bottleplace[i, 0] = Int32.Parse(c[0]);
                bottleplace[i, 1] = Int32.Parse(c[1]);
                bottleplace[i, 2] = Int32.Parse(c[2]);
                bottleplace[i, 3] = Int32.Parse(c[3]);
            }
            int[,] bulletplace = new int[m, 2];//объявления массива попаданий пуль
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)//перебор элементов массива пуль
            {
                string[] c = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');//принятие координат
                bulletplace[i, 0] = Int32.Parse(c[0]);
                bulletplace[i, 1] = Int32.Parse(c[1]);           
                temp = 1;
                for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)//сравнение массивов(если X и Y пули меньше X и Y верхней точки и больше нижней, то присвоить значение = номеру мишени, иначе -1)
                {
                    if (bulletplace[i, 0] >= bottleplace[z, 0] & bulletplace[i, 0] <= bottleplace[z, 2] & bulletplace[i, 1] >= bottleplace[z, 1] & bulletplace[i, 1] <= bottleplace[z, 3])
                    {
                        mas[i] = z + 1;
                        temp = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (temp != 0)
                {
                    mas[i] = -1;
                }
                else if(i > 0)
                {
                    for(int x = i - 1; x >= 0; x--)//исключение повторяющихся попаданий по одной и той же мишени
                    {
                        if(mas[x] == mas[i])
                        {
                            mas[i] = -1;
                        }
                    }
                }               
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(mas[i]);
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Выполнял тест, в котором ограничений во времени 2 секунды, количество выстрелов и мишеней выдается произвольное количество до 100000, а значения координат от -10^9 до 10^9, при тестах выдает ошибку, "Time limit exceeded"

Comment: А какие проблемы сейчас у данного кода?

Comment: Для начала я бы разбил бы его хотя бы на методы. Сейчас код слишком стирилен и читается с усилиями...

Comment: проблема у кода во времени исполнения

Comment: Добавил комментарии

Comment: `проблема у кода во времени исполнения` - вы это серьезно? Как и чем измеряли время?

Comment: выполнял тест, в котором ограничений во времени 2 секунды, количество выстрелов и мишеней выдается произвольное количество до 100000, а значения координат от -10^9 до 10^9, при тестах выдает ошибку, "Time limit exceeded"

Comment: Тут задержка может быть только в `string[] c = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');` - недостаточно быстро вводите данные на каждой итерации.

Comment: Не подскажeте, что можно использовать вместо этого?

Comment: Тута есть только одно очевидное решение: сначала запросить и получить исходные данные, а потом уже с ними производить какие-то вычисления. По поводу скорости работы [см.видео](https://youtu.be/t-Yf-c4FoXg?t=579)

Comment: Исправил все-таки, заменив массив расположения бутылок на список, там прям уже максимально быстро должно происходить вычисление, ибо уже сбитые мишени удаляются, а не идет сортировка в дальнейшем, можно было еще ввести дополнительную переменную(счетчик) и добавить ветвление(если мишень использована, перевести ее в начало массива, перебор массива начинать со следующего элемента), но к тому моменту уже пришлось танцевать с бубном вокруг списков, поэтому решил так). Видео посмотрел, на самом деле я с ним согласен, хотя и являюсь говнокодером, но оптимизации требовало задание)